# SSAS Tabular table always shows in Excel

Tags: database, ssas, dax, tabular, ssas-tabular

In my SSAS tabular model I have a calendar dimension, and a wave dimension for half-year data only. The data flows to these tables as such:

Fact Table ---> Wave Dim <---> Calendar

No matter what I do I cannot hide the wave table from Excel users. The table shows hidden in Visual Studio, but in Excel it shows the table with no fields in it. I have tried deleting the table and reloading it with no avail. My assumption is that it has to do with the way it's connected to the Calendar dimension, but I can't seem to find anything on my issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one to answer without viewing your model.bim file. Based on your information I have two guesses on what could be the issue, although this may very well not be it:
1) It sounds like you've marked all fields in the Wave table as hidden, but not the Wave table itself. Could this be the reason?
2) Perhaps you are using perspectives, and only hid the Wave table in a perspective rather than in the Model (default perspective)?

The relationships in your model should have no impact on whether a table is displayed in client tools or not.

Feel free to upload your model.bim file if the above does not help.

Comment: Unfortunately there is too much sensitive info in the .bim for me to scrub. I have verified I am not using perspectives and both tables are hidden from client view. The tables are only showing in the Excel pivot table drop down menu, but not in the box below the search bar. I found one response to this issue on this site, but it was back in 2013 with no official fix. It was just chalked up as a bug. But that was a long time ago.